# I dont understand how the different amounts are calculated

Tags: java

I don't understand how the results are calculated

```
int halfDollar = remainingAmount / 50;
remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 50;

int numberOfQuarters = remainingAmount / 25;
remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 25;
```

ETC.....

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program3
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the total dollar amount in the piggy bank: $");
        double amount = kbd.nextDouble();

        int remainingAmount = (int)(amount * 100);

        int halfDollar = remainingAmount / 50;
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 50;

        int numberOfQuarters = remainingAmount / 25;
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 25;

        int numberOfDimes = remainingAmount / 10;
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 10;

        int numberOfNickels = remainingAmount / 5;
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 5;

        int numberOfPennies = remainingAmount;


        System.out.println(String.format("In $" + "%.2f", amount) + " worth of pennies there are:");
        System.out.println(halfDollar + " half dollar(s), " + numberOfQuarters + " quarter(s), " + numberOfDimes + " dime(s), " + numberOfNickels + " nickle(s), and " + numberOfPennies + " cent(s).");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ask whoever wrote this code?

Comment: I wrote it based on examples in the book in order to solve my homework. I just want to fully understand how exactly this was solved.

Comment: Do you understand what the `/` and `%` operators do?

Comment: Maybe you should ask a specific question (something like what is the `%`  operator?)

Comment: I do, so is remainingAmount given a different value once it is (/) ?

Comment: Take a look at java's operator documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Comment: When you do something like `int halfDollar = remainingAmount / 50;` then remainingAmount doesn't change. It does change when you do something like `remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 50;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, you multiple the number of dollars by 100 and you get the number of cents, then you calculate how many nickels, dimes etc that would be.

For example, $5.26 is 526 cents, which is 10 half dollars ($5), 1 quarter, 1 penny.

Integer division gives you the number of times X is contained in Y, and modulus (%) gives you the remainder.

```
526 / 50 = 10
526 % 50 = 26

26 / 25 = 1
26 % 25 = 1

1 / 10 = 0
1 % 10 = 1

1 / 5 = 0
1 % 5 = 1

1 / 1 = 1
1 % 1 = 0
```

Obviously, what that does is break the amount of money in the least number of coins by giving you as many coins of the highest denomination first, then the highest number of coins of the next denomination etc.

Comment: I think 576 % 50 = 26.

Comment: The math doesn't quite check out here. 576/50 = 11 and 576%50 = 26

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking 5.26 then switched half way through, thus the mess. I fixed it now.

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies everything.

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding fractions you multiply value with 100. Making calculations with fractions is a little bit difficult. 
For example instead of making calculations with $1.25 programmers prefer to make calculations 125. It makes to easy understanding.

If you divide(/)  X to Y you find the number of Y that X contains.
If you take mod(%) X of Y you find the remainder of X divided by Y

```
Think that $1.43 entered.

1.43 * 100 = 143
143 / 50 = 2 -> Half dollar
143 % 50 = 43 -> remainder of division

43 / 25 = 1 -> Quarter
43 % 25 = 18 -> remainder of division

18 / 10 = 1 -> Dimes
18 % 10 = 8 -> remainder of division

8 / 5 = 1 -> Nickels
8 % 5 = 3 -> remainder of division

There is no more division last remainder is pennies and it is 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/` operator when applied to `int`s provides integer division. That is: division where the fractional part is thrown away.

For example: `10 / 3` gives `3`.

Since:

- `10` divided by `3` is `3.3333333` recurring.
- Throwing away the fractional part (`0.3333333` recurring) gives the result **`3`**.

---

The `%` operator provides modulus or the remainder of integer division. That is: the numerator minus the greatest multiple of the denominator that is less than the numerator.

For example: `10 % 3` gives `1`.

Since:

- the numerator is `10`
- the denominator is `3`
- The result of the integer division `10 / 3` is `3` (as we worked out above)
- The greatest multiple of the denominator (`3`) that is less than the numerator (`10`) is 3, since `3 * 3` is `9` and no multiple of `3` is greater than `9` but less than `10`.
- Subtracting that (`9`) from the numerator (`10`) you get `10 - 9` which is the result **`1`**.

An easier way to understand this is that integer `/` is division of whole things that can't be split. So you might want to divide 10 marbles (which you don't want to split into pieces) evenly between 3 people. Then each person gets 3 marbles, but there is 1 marble left over.

Note: that the greatest multiple of the denominator is exactly the result of the integer division (`3` in this case, as in `10 / 3` is **`3`**)

Note: You could also work this out by multiplying the fractional part by the result of the integer division (which we worked out was `10 / 3 =`**`3`**). Giving `0.33333... * 3` which is the result **`1`**.