# Counting Change Program - C

Tags: c, casting

I ran into a peculiar problem when trying to write a program for counting out change for a user. The user would enter in an amount -- in dollars and cents -- and the program would compute how many bills and coins the user would receive.

I have issues with counting out the coins portion, as I am not calculating the amount I expect to be calculating.

For example, the user would input `123.45` so I would pull the `123` out and compute the dollars portion, and then pull the `.45` and compute the coins portion.

I feel like there is an issue with casting a floating-point number to an integer, but I'm not sure. If I enter `.45` and then try and print it, the program would output `.449997` instead.

What's going on here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void giveChange(float);
void countCents(float);

int main()
{
    float amount;

    printf("Enter in an amount (in dollars and cents): ");
    scanf("%f", &amount);

    giveChange(amount);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void giveChange(float amount)
{
    int newAmount = (int)amount;
    int hundreds, fifties, tens, fives, ones;
    float cents = amount - newAmount;

    hundreds = newAmount / 100;
    newAmount %= 100;

    fifties = newAmount / 50;
    newAmount %= 50;

    tens = newAmount / 10;
    newAmount %= 10;

    fives = newAmount / 5;
    newAmount %=  5;

    printf("\nHundreds: %i\nFifties: %i\nTens: %i\nFives: %i\nOnes: %i\n", hundreds, fifties, tens, fives, newAmount);

    countCents(cents);

    return; 
}

void countCents(float cents)
{
    int newCents = cents * 10;
    int quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;

    quarters = newCents / 25;
    newCents %= 25;

    dimes = newCents / 10;
    newCents %= 10;

    nickels = newCents / 5;
    newCents %= 5;

    printf("\nQuarters: %i\nDimes: %i\nNickels: %i\nPennies: %i\n", quarters, nickels, dimes, newCents);

    return;
}
```

Comment: A side note. You are using Greedy approach. If you need to minimize the # of coins used, you should try using dynamic programming technique

Comment: The problem is that computers use discrete maths, and since they don't have infinite memory, where you see one number they see another one (not exactly like that and depends of the number, but to have a general idea).

Comment: This question has been answered a number of times. Just search.

Comment: Stop using `float`, use `int`. With `int newAmount = (int)amount;` passed as a `float`, what is the point? You'll only get rounding errors.

Comment: Why are you doing this `newCents = 10 * cents`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I dont understand how the different amounts are calculated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216438/i-dont-understand-how-the-different-amounts-are-calculated)

Comment: Weather Vane: I'm using that statement to extract the `100` out of a `100.34` iharob: I'm using that statement to make computation simpler, where I can divide by `25` instead of `.25`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't represent change with a float.  You need to treat money as an integral number of cents (or tenths of a cent, hundredths of a cent, &ct depending on application).

Try something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int dollars;
  int cents;

  scanf ("%d.%d", &dollars, &cents);

  printf ("%d dollars, %d cents\n", dollars, cents);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! I had no idea you could use `scanf()` with decimal places like that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You are using floating-point data types to represent fixed-point calculations. Floating-point arithmetic is subject to a number of rounding errors such as those you've seen.

Instead of using `float` or `double` to represent dollars and fractions, use a plain `int` representing the total amount of *cents*. For example, instead of using `float value = 4.25;` for $4.25, use `int value = 425;` (425 cents) instead. Then, `value/100` (`== 4`) is the number of dollars (note: integer division is truncated), and `value%100` (`== 25`) is the number of pennies.

(This is called '[fixed-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic)' since the decimal point position is fixed in the representation (in this case, it is always after exactly two decimal digits). Fixed-point arithmetic is basically integer arithmetic with post-calculation corrections.)

Answer (score 0):

Long story short floats do not work like ints and thus you cannot express precise numbers with them.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

Try multiplying the input by 100 and then using %100!