# Least number of stamps needed to pay certain postage

Tags: c, algorithm

I wrote a C program to solve the stamp and postage problem using brute force. However, it looks really stupid... Is there any better algorithms there to find the fewest number of stamps needed to pay certain postage?

```
const int denominations[] = {1, 5, 17, 23, 37, 50};
int stamps[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

void ALG2(int p) { //p means postage
    int least = p;
    int i[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    for (i[0] = 0; i[0] <= p / denominations[0]; i[0]++) { 
        for (i[1] = 0; i[1] <= p / denominations[1]; i[1]++) {
            for (i[2] = 0; i[2] <= p / denominations[2]; i[2]++) {
                for (i[3] = 0; i[3] <= p / denominations[3]; i[3]++) {
                    for (i[4] = 0; i[4] <= p / denominations[4]; i[4]++) {
                        for (i[5] = 0; i[5] <= p / denominations[5]; i[5]++) {
                            if (getSum(i) == p) {
                                if (getCount(i) < least) {
                                    least = getCount(i);
                                    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                                        stamps[j] = i[j];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a different spin on the [make correct change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995888/counting-change-program-c) problem. Take a look at the modulo operator `%`

Comment: @yano Yes.. 
but that algorithm does not returns the best combination of stamps.

For instance, when p = 127, that algorithm will return 
- $50 x 2, $23 x 1 and $1 x 4 (7 stamps)
while the best combination is 
- $50 x 1, $37 x 1, $23 x 1 and $17 x 1 (4 stamps)

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Different problem all together then. Interesting, don't think I've encountered one like this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5 is evenly divisible by 1; so it never makes sense to have 5 or more 1 cent stamps. In other words, you can significantly reduce the worst case by doing `for (i[0] = 0; (i[0] <= p / denominations[0]) && (i[0] < 5); i[0]++) {`

What is the maximum number of 5 cent stamps that could make sense? You can determine this by using "lowest least common multiple":

```
LCM(5, 17) = 85 = less than (85/5) or 17 of the 5 cent stamps
LCM(5, 23) = 115 = less than (115/5) or 23 of the 5 cent stamps
LCM(5, 37) = 185 = less than (185/5) or 37 of the 5 cent stamps
LCM(5, 50) = 50 = less than (50/5) or 10 of the 5 cent stamps
Result: Less than 10 of the 5 cent stamps
```

What is the maximum number of 17, 23, or 37 cent stamps that could make sense? Same approach:

```
LCM(17, 23) = 391 = less than 23
LCM(17, 37) = 629 = less than 37
LCM(17, 50) = 850 = less than 50
Result: Less than 23 of the 17 cent stamps

LCM(23, 37) = 851 = less than 37
LCM(23, 50) = 1150 = less than 50
Result: Less than 37 of the 23 cent stamps

LCM(37, 50) = 1850 = less than 50
Result: Less than 50 of the 37 cent stamps
```

Also; LCM(5, 17, 23, 37, 50) = 723350. This means that if you want a higher amount of postage you can assume there must be at least `(p/723350)*(723350/50)` of the 50 cent stamps, or there must be at least `(p/723350)* 14467` of the 50 cent stamps. E.g. if someone wants 9999999 postage, then `(9999999/723350) * 14467 = 13 * 14467 = 188071`, so there must be at least 188071 of the 50 cent stamps.

For `getSum()`, you can keep track in each loop so that it only requires additions. E.g.:

```
    for (i[0] = 0, sum0 = 0; i[0] <= p / denominations[0]; i[0]++, sum0 += i[0]) { 
        for (i[1] = 0, sum1 = sum0; i[1] <= p / denominations[1]; i[1]++, sum1 += i[1]) {
            for (i[1] = 0, sum2 = sum1; i[1] <= p / denominations[1]; i[1]++, sum2 += i[2]) {
```

This allows you to improve efficiency (compared to doing `getSum()`); but more importantly it allows you to replace the inner loop with a modulo operation, like:

```
if(sum4 < p) {
    if( (p - sum4) % denominations[5] == 0) {
        i[5] = (p - sum4) / denominations[5];
        if (getCount(i) < least) {
```

By reversing the order of loops (so that 50 cent stamps are the outer-most loop and the 1 cent stamps are the inner-most loop) this gets even better because you know everything is divisible by 1:

```
if(sum1 < p) {
    i[0] = p - sum1;
    if (getCount(i) < least) {
```

It also allows you to be smarter about the loops (as mentioned by Reinstate Monica's answer). E.g.:

```
        for (i[2] = 0, sum2 = sum3; (i[2] <= (p - sum3) / denominations[2]) && (i[2] < 37); i[2]++, sum2 += denominations[2]) {
```

Now...

What if you had a small table containing the best answer for all postage values from 0 to 9, so if the amount of postage you're still looking for is less than 10 you can use the table to skip all the work in all the remaining inner loops, like:

```
    for (i[5] = 0, sum5 = 0; (i[5] <= p / denominations[5]) && (i[5] < 37); i[5]++, sum5 += denominations[5]) {
        if(p - sum5 < 10) {
            /* Use table to skip everything else */
        } else {
            for (i[4] = 0, sum4 = sum5; (i[4] <= (p - sum5) / denominations[4]) && (i[4] < 50); i[4]++, sum4 += denominations[4]) {
            if(p - sum4 < 10) {
                /* Use table to skip everything else */
            } else {
```

What if the table was a bigger and contained the best answer for all postage values from 0 to 999? Obviously, the larger the table is the more work you can skip and the faster it's going to be.

Taking into account the "LCM(5, 17, 23, 37, 50) = 723350" stuff from earlier; the maximum size table you'd need would have 723350 entries. At this point all the loops become unnecessary. It's probably too big to include a pre-calculated table in the program itself; but what if an entry in the table could be set to "currently unknown"?

In that case you could start with a small pre-calculated table (e.g. the best answer for all postage values from 0 to 99) to initialize the huge table; then do something like:

```
    for (i[5] = 0, sum5 = 0; (i[5] <= p / denominations[5]) && (i[5] < 37); i[5]++, sum5 += denominations[5]) {
        if(huge_table_entry[p - sum5].state != UNKNOWN) {
            /* Use table to skip everything else */
        } else {
            /* Determine answer for p - sum5 without using table, and then store
               the answer in the table in case it's needed again at some point */
```

Comment: Excellent! Expanding on the maximum quantities needed of face values below 50 cents, 4×1 + 9×5 + 9×17 + 36×23 + 49×37 = 2843, so for any postage above 2843 there must be at least ⌈(postage - 2843) / 50⌉ fifty cent stamps. That cuts down the size of a complete lookup table considerably!

Comment: @IanAbbott: Zero to four 1 cent pieces is 5 possibilities. You also can't add possibilities and need to multiply (e.g. consider binary - each bit has 2 possibilities, so 8 bits is `2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 256 possibilities` and not `2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 16 possibilities`). This just gives the same `5 * 10 * 17 * 23 * 37  = 723350`.

Comment: I thought you worked out that it doesn't make sense to have more than 4 one cent stamps, more than 9 five cent stamps, etc.?

Comment: @IanAbbott: I did. With only 4 possibilities the number of 1 cent stamps would be "zero, one, two or three" (which doesn't work - what if the answer involves four 1 cent stamps?).

Comment: Maybe I'm being thick. You never need more than 4 one cent stamps and more than 9 five cent stamps and ... and more than 49 thirty seven cent stamps, all of which total no more than 2843 cents. Any postage greater than 2843 cents can be split into the sum of a "high" part and a "low" part, with the "low" part being in the range 2794 to 2843 cents such that the "high" part is a multiple of 50 cents. The "high" part would be composed solely of 50 cent stamps and the "low" part would be composed of an optimal collection of stamps (possibly including some more 50 cent stamps).

Comment: @IanAbbott: Ah, I see what you're thinking. It doesn't work because you can't know how to split it into high and low, and can't know the right number of 50 cent stamps. E.g. consider `p = 60*50 + 37*2 = 3074`. Should it be `high = 250, low = 2824` (leading to the wrong answer) or `high = 3050, low = 24` (leading to the wrong answer) or...?

Comment: @IanAbbott: Hrm; actually you might be right. With a 2844 entry table, you could try every possible way of splitting it into high and low and get up to 57 possible answers, then see which one of those is the best answer.

Comment: Building up the 2844 entry table (including an entry for zero) is actually pretty easy and can be done in a single pass.

Comment: For your example, the "high" part would be 250 (5*50), but the "low" part can also contain some 50 cent stamps (and is likely to contain mostly 50 cent stamps).

Comment: I just noticed a slight typo in your answer: "Less than 10 of the 17 cent stamps" should be "Less than 23 of the 17 cent stamps". That increases the maximum "low" part to 3064 (requiring 3065 table entries including 0), and for postage above 3064 the "low" part would be the value in the range 3015 to 3064 such that the "high" part is a multiple of 50.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any better algorithms there to find the fewest number of stamps needed to pay certain postage?

Some ideas:

1. Rather than `for (i[n] = 0; i[n] <= p / denominations[n]; i[n]++) {`, only need to loop to `for (i[n] = 0; i[n] <= (p - current_sum)/ denominations[n]; i[n]++) {`
2. Loop first with largest denomination stamps first.
3. Quit the loops if the exact sum found.